# How to rotate text label anti-clockwise in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

i'm relatively new to qgis. I am using version 2.14.7. I would like to rotate a text label anti-clockwise in map composer but the Rotation settings in Item Properties only allow for clockwise rotation. What do I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, if you want to go, for example, `-90` degrees then just use `270`.

Comment: Is this a case that the text appears upside-down when you rotate it?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! If I put 360 degrees in the Rotate box to start with then I can rotate anticlockwise from there.